# phpmyadmin 5.1 autoload.php missing

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just recently installed phpmyadmin 5.1.1 with composer. When I go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` I get the following error:

> File ./autoload.php missing or not readable. Most likely you did not
> run Composer to install library files.

I've installed the library files with composer. The autoload.php file simply isn't there. I've tried copying the autoload.php file in the vendor directory and changing the line `require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';` to `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php';` but this did not work. The error message is gone but index.php couldn't load in the css and js files. Any help with this issue would be appreciated. I'm on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

Only question I found that was similar is this one: [Phpmyadmin File ./autoload.php missing or not readable. NO COMPOSER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669397/phpmyadmin-file-autoload-php-missing-or-not-readable-no-composer) but there's no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by copying the autoload.php file from the phpmyadmin folder for version 4.9 into my new phpmyadmin folder and this worked for me.